# meaning of "funky girl"?

Tags: vocabulary

Although i tried searching google but couldn't came across any digestible stuff
my question is that[image]
if a young girl in her early twenties  make an email id as "funkygirl", what is the meaning of "funky"here?

i have also attached a photo containing the word"funky"discussing about  a young girl in showbiz"
so what is meaning of funky here?

Comment: The modern slang usage ***funky*** is almost always "approving, positive", but the exact intended meaning in any given context is highly variable / imprecise. Probably a good starting position is [***Unconventional or eccentric; offbeat or odd***](https://www.yourdictionary.com/funky) (note that your example will ***not*** carry any overtones of the far more dated sense of ***unpleasant smelling***).

Comment: ...there's also ***funky** = [overcome with great fear; terrified.*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/funky) I'd say that's dated UK public schoolboy slang (again, not relevant to your context, but it does "bleed into" the still-current sense of ***thrilling, exciting***).